# How do I chain devise_for calls in my route file? - Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to use OmniAuth, and according to Ryan Bates, I should override the Devise Registration controller by specifying the following `devise_for` scope in my `routes.rb` file:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
```

However, according to `Devise's` documentation, if I am to customize the path_names, so instead of doing `mydomain.com/users/sign_up/`, I can do `mydomain.com/register`, I would have to do something like this:

```
devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_up => "register", :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :settings => "settings", :newpass => "newpass", :changepass => "changepass" }
```

I tried to chain both of them like this:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}, :path_names => { :sign_up => "register", :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout", :settings => "settings", :newpass => "newpass", :changepass => "changepass" }
```

But that doesn't work. In order for me to go to the view in my `views/registrations/new.html.erb`, I have to go to `mydomain.com/users/register`. If I go to `mydomain.com/register` it still serves it from `/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb`.

How do I get `mydomain.com/register` to point to `/views/registrations/new.html.erb`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write this in you routes file instead of adding `:path_name`

```
devise_scope :user do
   get "register", :to => "devise/registrations#new"
   get "login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
   get "logout", :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
end
```

_edit2_*_*

If you want to override the controllers then you need to copy the devise controller folder from your gem into your application under app/controllers. In this case You also need to write below lines in routes.rb file. If you don't want to override the default functionality for devise controllers then there is no need to adding below lines in routes.rb file.

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {
      :registrations => 'devise/registrations',
      :sessions => 'devise/sessions',
      :passwords => 'devise/passwords',
      :confirmations => 'devise/confirmations',
      :unlocks => 'devise/unlocks'
  }
```

Comment: Perfect this works...I just have one question, this is how my `routes.rb` looks now:  `devise_for :users, :controllers =>{:registrations => 'registrations'}` `devise_scope :user do
    get "login", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "register", :to => "registrations#new"
  get "settings", :to => "registrations#edit"
    get "logout",   :to => "devise/sessions#destroy"
  get "newpass", :to => "devise/passwords#new"
  get "changepass",  :to => "devise/passwords#edit"
  end`

Comment: Given that I am sending all requests in the `devise_for` to the controller `registrations`, do I have to do anything different for those actions not in `registrations`? Namely `logout, changepass, login, etc.`?